# Firefox WebExtension - Is there a way to unique identify browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've started to work on a bookmark syncing plugin that allows you to choose profiles certain folder belong to. With the idea that each profile can be synced using whatever cloud storage you want as well as manually. This would allow specific profiles of bookmarks to be shared to different computers.

I'm currently looking and failing to find a way to easily get a identify from the browser to identify the current machine or profile, so I can handle mapping bookmark folders between multi pcs.

If there's not a decent way, i"d likely utilise a UUID or similar auto generated after the addon is installed, though I'd prefer to use something built-it to the web extension api.

Can anyone help suggest web extension ways to uniquely identify a browser/profile.

Comment: Although many different devices will have the same one, you can take a look at the user agent (`navigator.userAgent`)

Comment: ... and not just `navigator.userAgent`, there's a lot of information of the client in [`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) object.